# Can anybody please assist with syntax in a function in postgresql (from mysql)

Tags: postgresql, function, syntax

I am trying to create the following function in PostgreSQL but get the following error. This is from a MySQL procedure that I need to convert to PostgreSQL. I am failing to convert the syntax to PostgreSQL. I am a beginner in PostgreSQL. Please assist me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.usp_failed_analyze4()
RETURNS TABLE(status varchar) as
$BODY$
    SET @maxdate = (SELECT MAX(analyzetime) FROM  wp_analyze_history);
    SET @maxdateint = (SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW() ,MAX(analyzetime)) FROM  wp_analyze_history);
    SET @STATUS = SELECT Status from wp_analyze_history WHERE Status NOT IN ('OK','Table is already up to date','The Analyze task DID NOT run!') AND  analyzetime = @maxdate);
    SET @STATUSNOTRUN = 'The Analyze task DID NOT run!';
    IF @maxdateint > 7
    THEN SELECT @STATUSNOTRUN;
    ELSE SELECT @STATUS as "";
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE sql;
```

error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "@"
Position: 109

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I did read through the mentioned doc's before posting here, I am just not winning. I can see samples of setting something like x int etc, but not setting x as a whole query.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you want as you tried to copy the MySQL 1:1.

However, there are several problems in your code:

1. `language sql` does not have variables or IF statements. You need to use PL/pgSQL (`language plpgsql`)
2. PL/pgSQL requires a `declare` block to declare all variables and the actual code needs a `begin ... end;` block as well.
3. You can use `SET` for [assignment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT)
4. To [store the result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) of a single row query in a variable use `select ... into ... from`
5. The character `@` is invalid in an SQL identifier and can't be used for variable names (which follow the rules of SQL identifiers). In Postgres it's a common habit to prefix variable with something to avoid ambiguity with column names. I use `l_` for local variables (but that's completely a personal preference)
6. You don't seem to want to return multiple rows, but a single value. So you don't need `returns table`
7. To [return](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) something from a function, use `return` not `select`

Putting that all together it should look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usp_failed_analyze4()
  RETURNS varchar -- return a single value
AS
$BODY$
declare
  l_maxdate timestamp;
  l_maxdatediff interval;
  l_status text;
  l_statusnotrun text;
begin    
    select MAX(analyzetime), current_timestamp - MAX(analyzetime)
      into l_maxdate, l_maxdatediff
    FROM  wp_analyze_history;

    SELECT Status 
      into l_status
    from wp_analyze_history 
    WHERE Status NOT IN ('OK','Table is already up to date','The Analyze task DID NOT run!') 
      AND analyzetime = l_maxdate;
      
    l_statusnotrun := 'The Analyze task DID NOT run!';
    IF l_maxdatediff > interval '7 days' 
    THEN 
      return l_statusnotrun;
    ELSE 
      return ''; -- strings are enclosed in single quotes in SQL
    end if;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There is still room for a lot of optimization, but this matches your initial code as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped me a lot. Also to understand functions in PostgreSQL a lot better.